# Implement text valditation on li item in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement `input` that is in `li` component text validation. Basically when the user types text, it is send to backend and checked (returns if input is valid). If it's valid, user can post it.

```html
<li *ngFor="let value of values" [ngClass]="{'danger': !isValid}">
  <input [value]="value.title" (keyup)="onTitleChange($event)"/>
  <button [ngClass]="{'disabled': !isValid}">Post</button>
</li>
```

What I want to do is check input value and based on it put classes and li and button components. Every input value is independent from other li components.

I tried to accomplish this by using forms but it wasn't the solution I was looking for or maybe I was implementing it the wrong way. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you considered to use Reactive Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have common `isValid` component property , if you change it once it will get applied on all `li` elements.

This is how you can achieve what you are trying.

each`value` object in `values` should have one more property `isValid` which you can set to false/ true inside your `onTitleChange` method, make sure to pass `value` as a parameter to `onTitleChange`.

Here are code changes , let me know if you need any more explaination.

HTML

```html
<li *ngFor="let value of values" [ngClass]="{'danger': !value.isValid}">
  <input [value]="value.title" (keyup)="onTitleChange(value)"/>
  <button [ngClass]="{'disabled': !value.isValid}">Post</button>
</li>
```

TS

```js
onTitleChange(value:any) {
  //based on your http response set isValid property to true or false.(setting false for now)
  value.isValid = false;    
}
```